# How does Rails' profile_path in #link_to accept an argument even though it's a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), If `profile_path` is just a variable that = the string `"/profiles/"` how can it accept an argument like `@profile`? Is this part of Rails magic?

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)
# => <a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>
```

Comment: `profile_path` is a method

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

Comment: Don't confuse profiles with profile

Comment: more importantly why do you think `profile_path` is a variable set to a string? Where did this idea come from?

Answer (score 1):

`profile_path` isn't just a variable set to a string.

`profile_path` is a [path helper *method*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) that accepts arguments and returns a string.